# View behind UINavigationBar in UIViewController with two UITableView in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tableview, navigationbar

Using iOS7 I have 2 `UITableView` in `UIViewController` sharing half of the screen vertically. When the view is loaded the left `tableView` is displayed correctly starting below the translucent `navigationBar` and goes behind it when the `tableView` is scrolled up. But the problem is with the right `tableView` because it is starting from top of the screen which is behind the translucent `navigationBar`.

Can anyone help me out on this as I need right `tableView` below the `navigationBar` and when I scroll it goes behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the system does not update the content insets correctly for the table views.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.tableView2.contentInset = self.tableView1.contentInset;
    self.tableView2.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView1.scrollIndicatorInsets;
}
```